# HEVC for decoding erroneous frame

Tags: h.264, hevc

I am trying to design a video transmission system for HEVC standard.  I have installed and compiled HEVC with the help of (JCTVC HM Software Manual). The problem is that whenever I simulate the HEVC for  decoding erroneous frames, the Decoder fails to operate/decode those frames, showing the message "Assertion 'binVal' failed". Could you please help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, legacy HM software does not support so-called packet-loss, like in JSVM (Scalable AVC).